# Find the largest continuous string without spaces in datatable column

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to find if there is any predefined way to find out the largest continuous string without space in datatable column

Example in datatable there is one column

```
Column1
=======

UnitedStatesofAmerica is large
India is large
London is large
```

So the largest continuous string should be UnitedStatesofAmerica  in first cell of the column

Do we have any predefined way ?

Comment: If you do it in C# code you will end up reading all rows from that database. Just something to consider if your database is large.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>{
    "UnitedStatesofAmerica is large",
    "India is large",
    "London is large"
};

var usa = strings.SelectMany(x => x.Split())
                 .OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
                 .First();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help. can you formulate the expression using DataTable. Thanks again

Comment: It can be something like this `var strings = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => (string)r["Column1"]).ToList();`

Comment: Bones question Is there any way to make the DataGridView column based upon the longest string?